# How to wait for one of many conditions with watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I am writing a Ruby (1.9.3) script (my first) using the watir-webdriver (0.6.4) gem. I am using it to open a site at a set interval, post some data, and then see if a text value appears on the page.

If I am simply looking for the word "hello" to appear on the page after it loads, I can use this command:

```
Watir::Wait.until(timeout = 10) {b.text.include? 'hello'}
```

However, I am looking for the word 'hello' OR the word 'goodbye' so functionally I want to do this:

```
Watir::Wait.until(timeout = 10) {b.text.include? 'hello' or b.text.include? 'goodbye'}
```

But apparently that is not legal syntax. My current work around is to try the first condition (check for 'hello') and when the Timeout exception occurs (assuming 'hello' is not found), try the second condition (check for 'goodbye'). It seems inefficient (waiting for timeouts). Is there a better way?

Comment: Make sure you are working with Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `||` instead of `or` since it has a higher precedence over the latter:

```
Watir::Wait.until(timeout = 10) { b.text.include?('hello') || b.text.include?('goodbye') }
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, add more parentheses.

I don't know the specifics of how the ruby parser works, but I can understand why

```
b.text.include? 'hello' or b.text.include? 'goodbye'
```

Would cause problems. Try something like:

```
(b.text.include?('hello')) or (b.text.include?('goodbye'))
```

Or, as a simpler solution, you could  use a regex:

```
/hello|goodbye/ === b.text
```

Comment: There is  `||` which has higher precedence than `or`. Oh, and `===` is not idiomatic (never saw it before in this context). It does work since it is [a synonym](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) for the better known `=~`.

Comment: @steenslag it is not a synonym, `=~` returns a starting index (or -1) while `===` gives a boolean.

Comment: Well [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) named it a synonym, but I agree it's not. ((or -1) in your comment should should read (or `nil`)? )

Comment: Yes it should be `nil` sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to cache b.text first, and to avoid assignments in the method calls:

```
timeout = 10
Watir::Wait.until timeout do
  txt = b.text
  txt.include? 'hello' or txt.include? 'goodbye'
end
```

It is good if you learn the differences between `||` and `or`, but using `or` in this particular case is OK.